# Film with a genie transported to modern England and trapped in a television set

Tags: story-identification, movie

I believe it was a two part TV movie, but I could be wrong about this.
What I remember is that it started with the description of the wizard believing he is greater then Allah, and thus Allah cursed him and changed him into the Genie. But, he was not forced to live in the oil lamp, but instead he was "moved" to modern England, where he would be called through a TV screen.
The actual story starts long after the Genie has found its way how to live in this strange world and thus he has became an "English man" playing bridge with his neighbours, etc.

So basically the genie is helping the main protagonists (I do not remember much about them, they were just a man and a woman) with the modern items like a motorcycle which is invisible to everyone other than the master of the Genie.

For example, the motorcycle is brought by the genie to the "masters" in such a way that the Genie created a ramp to the TV screen and rode it through his living room to the screen to the old "Arab" desert where the main story is taking place.

Another scene I remember is, I believe, from almost at the end of the movie, where the Genie is driving the main male protagonist using a helicopter, and the main male protagonist asks the Genie to land at the market so they can have better style. Since no one else is seeing the helicopter, they are just seeing the man in it, "floating in the air", and since they can hear the loud noise and notice the heavy wind created by the helicopter, everyone escapes from the market with a fear of magic. The main male protagonist then steals a carpet, and puts it on the floor of the helicopter and sits on it, so to everyone, it now seems that he is driving a magic flying carpet.

- I have seen this around 1997 - 2006
- I believe that the origin of the movie is England because of the Genie character, but just my guess
- I have seen it in Czech Republic on TV but the movie was definitively not Czech

Comment: Hi there! :) When did you watch this? Was it in English, was it a translation? If this was broadcasted on TV (likely then?), any recollection of the channel it could have aired on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Philippe de Broca's 1990 *[1001 Nights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1001_Nights_(film))* (*Les 1001 Nuits*) as per this entry in *[Fairy-Tale Films Beyond Disney: International Perspectives](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mc-PCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=film%20genie%20motorcycle%20helicopter&source=bl&ots=Qk7qy53QeS&sig=XoPAr7osO051AtLkAWrE6_A7UTM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI3oLs5bjdAhVoxFkKHXZGAFkQ6AEwEXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage)*

From [the IMDB entry](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098961/):

> A satirical subversive take on the 1001 Nights legend that skips all the stories and puts Scheherazade herself at the center of the adventure. In ancient times, nubile but virginal Scheherazade must use her charms and wits to escape the Middle Eastern king who plans to bed her whether she likes it or not. She's helped on her journey by an astrologist from her own time teleported by a genie to present day London, where he became a proper English gentleman in order to fit it. Whenever Scheherazade is in trouble, he uses the time portal in his TV set to travel back and forth through time and send her the help she needs, including anachronistic escape vehicles like a motorcycle or an airplane. After temporarily teaming up with a couple of more allies, visiting London and losing all of her clothes more than once in the process, Scheherazade realizes that she can't just run forever and comes up with a risky plan.

### Trailer

The film achieved little acclaim on its release, but is now known as being the first film role of Catherine Zeta Jones.

Found via search terms of `film genie motorcycle helicopter` (not my first set of search terms, but the ones which worked).